# Minify multiple JS files with Uglifyjs for maintaining the same variables across all files if any

Tags: javascript, minify

Helllo,
i am using uglify JS to minify multiple js files individually but want to maintain the same global variables with --name cache command not working for me,

followed this article
https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

the below lines not working
$ rm -f /tmp/cache.json  # start fresh
$ uglifyjs file1.js file2.js --mangle-props --name-cache /tmp/cache.json -o part1.js

taken empty json file but not working...
is there any template for this scenario to maintain the json file...

help appriciated.

--Suneel

Comment: you can define global variables using window.varname ;p, just a suggestion, I know not a best practice

Comment: the problem is a global variable using in multiple json files, so the name which is compressed or mangled should be in sync all files...